# Understanding of javadoc for TreeItem

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Can someone explain why javadoc for TreeItem uses FXCollections.observableArrayList to create the local children variable, rather than ArrayList e.g.

```
private ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> buildChildren(TreeItem<File> TreeItem) {
          File f = TreeItem.getValue();
          if (f != null && f.isDirectory()) {
              File[] files = f.listFiles();
              if (files != null) {
                  ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> children = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                  for (File childFile : files) {
                      children.add(createNode(childFile));
                  }

                  return children;
              }
          }

          return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
      }
```

The returned collection is then added as follows

```
@Override public ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> getChildren() {
          if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
              isFirstTimeChildren = false;

              // First getChildren() call, so we actually go off and 
              // determine the children of the File contained in this TreeItem.
              super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren(this));
          }
          return super.getChildren();
      }
```

Since super.getChildren() is already an ObservableList, what is the advantage of adding an ObservableList to an ObservableList.  In my code I created the child items using ArrayList and added a valueChangedListener on the root node and received the event when setting value on a child item.

The javadoc for TreeView on the other hand add TreeItem elements separately and does not wrap them in ObservableList.

Is there something special going on here?

Comment: I think you are correct here. `ObservableList.setAll(Collection)` clears the list and then adds all the elements of the provided collection (firing only a single change event, so it is more efficient than calling `clear()` and then `addAll(...)`). So the `ObservableList` constructed in `buildChildren(...)` is only temporarily in scope and never has any listeners; it may as well be a regular `List` implementation. The overhead is likely pretty minimal, as no additional listeners are ever fired, but it should probably be a plain `List`.